# Broadcast in React with Expo project

Tags: react-native, expo

I am relatively new in react with expo project.

I can set variable and send across different screens using state/props.

```
this.state = {
  name: "Student name",
}
```

How can I send this information to all screen ? (like broadcast). I am using react with expo and I cannot find information currently from documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create sample expo snack with observer pattern:

1.MessageCenter class implements observer pattern.

2.Home Screen subscribed to message in componentDidMount.

3.Settings Screen have a button "Send Message" that send data  to Screens that  was subscribed like  HomeScreen.

https://snack.expo.io/H1LG85H5B

Comment: Can you please share code for MessageCenter and elaborate?

Comment: Did you open the link  provided with expo snack in answer  on PC   and looked at project explorer tree? You can find the messagecenter source and you can also run it.(open with  Deskop browser)

Comment: oh..i see now.  Thanks a lot. it is brilliant solution.